# Flex Box Prefix for multiple browser

Tags: css, flexbox

I am just wondering what type of Flex Box Prefix for multiple browsers for code that I have below or is what I have enough.

Thank you in advance.

```
.icon-wrapper {
        margin: 100px 0 75px 0;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```
.icon-item {
        flex: 1 0 40%;
        height: 250px;
    }
```

Comment: using only flex is enough. check this out https://caniuse.com/?search=flex

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini so I can get rid of the -webkit-flex, -moz-flex; -ms-flex;

Comment: Yes, No need to use it. even IE9 supports it.